# this code gives 0 as height and width for the first time it iterates and the second time gives the right dimensions

Tags: javascript

```
var icon1 = new Image();
icon1.src = resource;
var width = icon1.width;
var height = icon1.height;
```

This code when iterates gives 0 as width and height for the first time it iterates and for the second time it gives right dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't really shown enough code (and general context) to be sure, but I'd wager that the first time, the image hasn't loaded, and the second time, it has.

Comment: this is the first time i posted on stackoverflow....so sorry about that..i am trying to maintain the aspect ratio of image...and the resource is the url of the image....so what can be done to get the height and width of image if its not loaded yet

Answer (score 1):

You can make sure the image has loaded first via the `onload` event.

```
var resource = "http://placehold.it/50";
var icon1 = new Image();
var wid1;
var hei1;

icon1.onload = function() {
    wid1 = icon1.width;
    hei1 = icon1.height;
    console.log(wid1);
    console.log(hei1);
};

icon1.src = resource;
```

Comment: This code works fine for images but sometimes there is a url of video as well from youtube....in that case same thing happens it doesnt load the video for first time but it loads it perfectly the second time.and thank you for introducing me to .onload function....any help on video thumbnail??

Comment: what does your video code look like? Or are you saying the `resource` variable could be a video URL?

Comment: I guess I don't see how a youtube url would even work as the `src` for an image, do you have a specific example?

Answer (score 0):

try assigning the resource to the src before defining the onload function.

```
    var resource = "http://placehold.it/50";
    var icon1 = new Image();
    var wid1;
    var hei1;

    icon1.src = resource;

    icon1.onload = function() {
        wid1 = icon1.width;
        hei1 = icon1.height;
        console.log(wid1);
        console.log(hei1);
    };
```

Comment: i did that...it works fine for images but for the video thumbnail it gives 0 as width and height for the first time it loads and perfect result the send time i load the same video...

Comment: Can you share the balance of the code which is generating the results your experiencing?